# How I can control the tabs so it can match this design

Tags: flutter

[image]

How I can control the tabs , so it can shows up like this design
I try but I can't control the space before and after tabs in TabBar.

Comment: can you please check it: https://blog.logrocket.com/flutter-tabbar-a-complete-tutorial-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you mean by controlling tabs but check the below code for tab bar implementation, along with drawers and appbar action icons.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3, //this is the number of tabs you need -- for your case it is 3
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[500],
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {
              //This is to show a snackbar message when search button is pressed. Remove it and put your own onpressed action code
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: const Text("Search Button Pressed"),
                  behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  shape: const StadiumBorder(),
                  action: SnackBarAction(
                    label: 'Dismiss',
                    disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
                    textColor: Colors.blue,
                    onPressed: () {
                      //Do whatever you want
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }, icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
          ],
          bottom: const TabBar(
            //customise your tabs here
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorWeight: 5,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            tabs: [
              //add your tabs here. if you add more tabs make sure you increase the length above
              Tab(text: 'Doctor', iconMargin: EdgeInsets.zero,),
              Tab(text: 'Community',),
              Tab(text: 'Calls',),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        //This is your app drawer
        drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              const DrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Item 1'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('Item 2'),
                onTap: () {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body:  const TabBarView(
          //This is the view of all the tabs. The first children in the list is the first item in tabs.
          children: [
            Center(child: Text('Doctor Page', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),)),
            Center(child: Text('Community Page', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),)),
            Center(child: Text('Calls Page', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30),)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]